# Angular - using a date pipe with ngModel

Tags: html, angular, date, input, date-pipe

I am getting the following error in my console - "Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'".

I have a calendar input, which should allow the user to select a date and then pass on that date in a certain format, 'dd/MM/yyyy'. I want the date selected to show in the calendar input once they have selected a date.

I realise I cannot have two way binding on the [ngModel] if I have a pipe there so I'm using
(ngModelChange). If I remove the #createdByCutOffDate="ngModel" then the error is removed but I cannot see the selected date show in the calendar input.

I also tried the updateCreatedByCutOffDate() method taking a date type or string.

this.createdByCutOffDate is in the following format - 'Thu Feb 17 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)'

component.html

```
<input type="date"
       id="createdByCutOffDate"
       [ngModel]="createdByCutOffDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"
       #createdByCutOffDate="ngModel"
       (ngModelChange)="updateCreatedByCutOffDate($event)" />
```

component.ts

```
createdByCutOffDate: Date;

updateCreatedByCutOffDate(date: string) {
    this.createdByCutOffDate = new Date(date);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`createdByCutOffDate` is a `Date` object that has its methods and properties.
So to solve your problem, use `"createdByCutOffDate.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"` instead of `"createdByCutOffDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for that! I hadn't seen anyone mention that. Appreciate it!

Comment: Have done so - has a time limit before you can mark as accepted hence the delay

Comment: Yeah I see, never mind